# Vee Validate field validation not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I have created a settings page where users can update their email addresses. Everything worked fine but suddenly the validation is not updating anymore. Only the first change of the input field triggers `validateState()`.

Any further changes will not trigger this function so the status of that field stays as it is.

I have compared the code with other components that use the same code and they still work fine.

I am using bootstrap-vue components for the form.

```html
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <b-form @submit="onSubmit">
                <b-form-group :label="$t('general.email')"
                            label-for="settingsEmail"
                            :invalid-feedback="errors.first('email')">
                    <b-form-input id="settingsEmail"
                                type="text"
                                v-model="form.email"
                                :disabled="saving"
                                name="email"
                                :state="validateState('email')"
                                v-validate="{required: true, email: true}">
                    </b-form-input>
                </b-form-group>
                <b-button type="submit" variant="primary" :disabled="saving || !hasChanged() || errors.any()"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw" v-if="saving"></i> {{$t('general.save')}}</b-button>
            </b-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {UPDATE_USER} from '../config/actions'

    export default {
        name: 'settingsAccount',
        data() {
            return {
                form: {},
                saving: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            user: function() {
                return this.$store.getters.getUser;
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.init();
        },
        methods: {
            init() {
                this.form.email = this.user.email;
            },
            hasChanged() {
                if(this.form.email !== this.user.email) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            },
            onSubmit(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.saving = true;

                this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        let data = {};

                        if(this.form.email !== this.user.email) {
                            data.email = this.form.email;
                        }

                        this.$store.dispatch(UPDATE_USER, data).then(() => {
                            this.saving = false;
                            this.$validator.reset();
                        }).catch(() => {
                            this.saving = false;
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.saving = false;
                    }
                });
            },
            validateState(ref) {
                if (this.veeFields[ref] && (this.veeFields[ref].dirty || this.veeFields[ref].validated)) {
                    return !this.errors.has(ref)
                }
                return null
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create codesandbox /codepen for the issue?

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're having is that the `form` data element is an empty object, so it will only trigger reactivity when the whole object changes.  Either you need to change your data to be this:

```
    data() {
        return {
            form: {email:''},
            saving: false
        }
    },
```

Or in your init function, explicitly add the email property as reactive:

```
    methods: {
        init() {
            this.$set(form,'email',this.user.email)
        },
        //...
```

If you're not clear on why, you can read the details here:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

A working example (minus vuex) here: https://codesandbox.io/s/x4kp93w3o

PS, when writing questions about vue, it's very helpful to boil it down to a simpler example.  Get rid of vuex, remove your translation stuff.  Sometimes the answer will jump out at you once you have it as simple as possible.